# Hopper to disassemble the UIKit.framework from Xcode

Tags: xcode9, hopper

I use **Hopper Disassembler** to disassemble the `UIKit.framework`. I usually select the binary from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit` but since I'm using Xcode 9 and later, I'm unable to find the binary to do the disassembling. The Xcode 8 `UIKit.framework` has the binary but the Xcode 9 `UIKit.framework` has only a `UIKit.tbd` file.

How can I achieve the disassemble in recent Xcodes?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Apple split up UIKit. The framework you are looking for is in
`../PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework`

**Xcode 10**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
```

---

**Xcode 11, 12, 13 & 14**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
```

---

**Xcode 15**

```
/Users/{USERNAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/{IPHONE_MODEL} ({IOS_VERSION})/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
```

Comment: In Xcode 9.4.1, the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks` folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Damn, that's a long path right there! But it works, thank you.

Comment: hi @mangerlahn there is only one uikit binary. Are there should be different binaries for iOS10, 11,  12 and so on?

Comment: Anyone found the path to SwiftUI framework yet?

Comment: in lldb `image list` will give u the list oof all loaded frameworks with their paths

Comment: It looks like the path has changed for Xcode 15, as the framework is no longer located within the Xcode app bundle. Instead, you can find it within user’s `Library` folder at `/Users/{USERNAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/{IPHONE_MODEL} ({IOS_VERSION})/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore`. Please share your results if this path works for you.

Comment: Yes, the path works for me as well. I'll update the answer. Thanks Lukáš!